# how to display 4-1 as month and date in php

Tags: php

I Am developing a php web application. Here I have date in a variable in the format 'm/d'

```
$var='04/25'
```

I have stored this value as strtotime with in my table

```
$var2=strtotime($var);
```

Then I need to display this value as `4-25` i.e. remove 0 from 04.
If the date is 1 I need to display 1 not 01

Does anyone know this?

Comment: You'll need a year, whether it's this year (2012) or another arbitrary year; PHP can't work with generic month/day strings like this.

Comment: @MartinBean try it - works fine ... uses the current year

Comment: From [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) manual  use `j`:Day of the month without leading zeros

Comment: @MartinBean If you don't specify a year, it'll take current year by default

Comment: @Aleks G Surely PHP will be assuming a year, though?

Comment: @MartinBean Yes, it'll assume current year.  If the OP doesn't care about the year, then there's no difference anyway.

Comment: @AleksG What about leap years?

Comment: What about it?  PHP is smart enough to deal with all of this.  Just read the docs on `strtotime` and `date` functions.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [PHP date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). In your case I would say `date("n-j", $var2);`

Answer (score 1):

Too many ways to do this, so let's go with one of them:

```
ltrim( $var, '0' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I always store timestamps, that way they can easily be used with date() function to convert them to any format I need.

```
$now = time();
print date("n-d",$now);
```

Comment: As Mads pointed out, you may also use "n-j" if 04/08 should be displayed as 4-8 instead of 4-08.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `date` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
echo date('n-j', $var2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this : 
   copy below code and past in test.php and after run you get the out put : 4-25

```
   <?php

        $date = "04/25";
        $temp = strtotime($date);
        echo date('n-j',$temp);

   ?>
```